Create and sign transaction with offline signer and ECDSA signatures
I would like to understand how to sign a balances.transferKeepAlive transaction completely offline with an existing signing service with ECDSA signatures.  This is what I have so far that is working:
const { ApiPromise, WsProvider } = require('@polkadot/api');
const { EXTRINSIC_VERSION } = require('@polkadot/types/extrinsic/v4/Extrinsic');
const { cryptoWaitReady, keccakAsHex } = require('@polkadot/util-crypto');
const { secp256k1 } = require('@noble/curves/secp256k1');
const crypto = require('node:crypto')
const { hexToU8a,u8aConcat, u8aToHex } = require('@polkadot/util');

class SigningService {
 constructor() {
   this.keys = {}
 }

 computePublicKeysFromPrivateKey({ key }) {
   return Promise.resolve({
     publicKeys: [
       { format: 'compressed', value: Buffer.from(secp256k1.getPublicKey(key, true)).toString('hex') },
       { format: 'uncompressed', value: Buffer.from(secp256k1.getPublicKey(key, false)).toString('hex').substring(2) }
     ]
   });
 }

 async importPrivateKey({ key }) {
   const id = crypto.randomUUID();
   const publicKeys = await this.computePublicKeysFromPrivateKey({ key });

   this.keys[id] = key;

   return Promise.resolve({ id, ...publicKeys });
 }

 async sign({ hash, id }) {
   const signature = secp256k1.sign(hash, keys[id]);
 
   return Promise.resolve({ recovery: signature.recovery, signature: signature.toCompactHex(), signatureFull: signature });
 }
}

const transferECDSA = async (to, from, amount) => {
 const keyService  = new SigningService();
 const { id: keyId } = await keyService.importPrivateKey({ key: '<private-key-hex-for-from>' });

 const RPC_ENDPOINT = 'wss://rococo-muse-rpc.polkadot.io';
 const wsProvider = new WsProvider(RPC_ENDPOINT);
 const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });

 await api.isReady;
 await cryptoWaitReady();

 const extrinsic = api.tx.balances.transferKeepAlive(to, amount);

 const signer = {
   signPayload: async payload => {
     const extrinsicPayload = api.registry.createType('ExtrinsicPayload', payload, { mode: 0, registry: api.registry, version: EXTRINSIC_VERSION });
     const extrinsicPayloadU8a = extrinsicPayload.toU8a({ method: true });
     const actualPayload = extrinsicPayloadU8a.length > 256 ? api.registry.hash(extrinsicPayloadU8a) : extrinsicPayloadU8a;
     const { recovery, signature } = await keyService.sign({ hash: keccakAsHex(actualPayload).substring(2), id: keyId });
     const recoveryU8a = Uint8Array.from([recovery || 0]);

     return { id: 1, signature: u8aToHex(u8aConcat(hexToU8a(signature), recoveryU8a)) };
   }
 };

 const signedExtrinsic = await extrinsic.signAsync(from, { signer });

 const unsub = await signedExtrinsic.send(({ status }) => {
   if (status.isInBlock) {
     console.log(`Transaction included at blockHash ${status.asInBlock}`);
   } else if (status.isFinalized) {
     console.log(`Transaction finalized at blockHash ${status.asFinalized}`);
     unsub();
     throw new Error('Exiting Process');
   }
 });
}

My goal is to be able to create the signer and sign completely offline.  Currently the    const extrinsicPayload = api.registry.createType('ExtrinsicPayload', payload, { mode: 0, registry: api.registry, version: EXTRINSIC_VERSION }); bit in the signer is keeping me from having the signer completely offline.  I have tried countless other approaches and I cannot generate a valid signature for some reason.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

The problem was that I was not generating the payload correctly.  I solved this by using createType where possible for generating the payload types E.G.
    const latestBlockHash = (await api.rpc.chain.getFinalizedHead()).toHex();
    const blockNumber = (await api.rpc.chain.getBlock(latestBlockHash)).block.header.number.toHex();
    const era = api.registry.createType('ExtrinsicEra', {
      current: blockNumber,
      period: 64
    });

    const nonceRaw = await api.call.accountNonceApi.accountNonce(from);
    const nonce = api.registry.createType('Compact<Index>', nonceRaw.toNumber());

    const payload = {
      address: from,
      blockHash: latestBlockHash,
      blockNumber,
      era: era.toHex(),
      genesisHash: api.genesisHash.toHex(),
      method: tx.method.toHex(),
      nonce: nonce.toHex(),
      signedExtensions: api.registry.signedExtensions,
      specVersion: api.runtimeVersion.specVersion.toHex(),
      tip: api.registry.createType('Compact<Balance>', 0).toHex(),
      transactionVersion: api.runtimeVersion.transactionVersion.toHex(),
      version: tx.version
    };

    const extrinsicPayload = api.registry.createType('ExtrinsicPayload', payload, {
      version: payload.version
    });

Then the signing generated a valid signature.
